# The ultimate goal

Tags: torah-study

I've been stuck wondering this question for a while now and I'm looking for someone to shed a really insightful answer.

**What is the ultimate goal a Jew should strive for concerning day to day life.
Not practically, ideally.**

Is the goal to be able to learn Torah (gemara, tanach, Mishna..) all day, everyday. Or maybe it's to learn often, but when you not learning (bowling for example) that you're doing it with midot and torah values? 
Or possibly something else.

Comment: have you seen chapter 1 of the Mesilat Yesharim?

Comment: No, I assume it addresses this exact point ?

Comment: See translation of Mesilat Yesharim [here](http://www.israel613.com/books/MESILAT_YESHARIM.pdf), ch. 1 starts bottom of p. 3

Comment: another one with useful commentaries [here](http://dafyomireview.com/mesilat.php?d=3&e=3). check out also gate 3 of chovos halevavos